# Section of a 4-dimensional cube

Tags: geometry

Consider 4-dimensional cube: $-1 \le x_1 \le 1, -1 \le x_2 \le 1,-1 \le x_3 \le 1, -1 \le x_4 \le 1$.

Could you show an octagon that is a section of this cube?

Comment: A cool question! This will take some imagination. Too bad you aren't asking for an octa*hedron* :-)

Comment: The section of the Tesseract  can be 3D shape normally 3D cube in the 4D inviroment.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is not a section by an hyperplane, but a skew polygon, whose vertices are the columns $C_{k}$ of this matrix:

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1&0&-1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&-1&0&-1&0&-1\\1&0&1&0&-1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&1&0&-1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

Proof: $\forall k=1 \cdots 7, \text{dist}(C_k,C_{k+1})=\sqrt{1^2+1^2+1^2+1^2}=2$ and dist($C_8,C_{1})=2$ as well.

It is a skew polygon.

Moreover, if one wants other such octagons, one can premultiply $M$ by a well chosen orthogonal matrix, for example, a permutation matrix.

Comment: I do not understand: the section of this hyperplane and the cube is a 3-dimensional figure, it can not be an octagon...

Comment: I have forgotten after I have made changes to erase the fact that they belong to an hyperplane: it is no longer true : it is a skew polygon.

Comment: I have made changes to my text. I recognize that, as such, it addresses a slightly different question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

First observe that it is possible to cut a cube in a way the cut is a regular hexagon.

Now extend that cube to the fourth dimension to get a tesseract (4D cube), and at the same time extend the cutting plane in the same direction to give a cutting hyperplane. This of course just adds an orthogonal dimension to the cut, so we get as cut figure a hexagonal prism.

Now we can cut the hexagonal prism with a plane so that of both hexagons, a part of a corner is cut away, so the cut is an octagon. That octagon is, of course, not regular, but that was not required.

This octagon is then, of course, also the cut of the two-dimensional plane with the four-dimensional tesseract.

For the coordinates of that polygon:

First, a hexagonal cut through a cube is, for example, given by the corners
$$(0,-1,-1), (-1,0,-1), (-1,1,0), (0,1,1), (1,0,1), (1,-1,0)$$
It is easily checked that those are, indeed, in a plane.

Extruding to the fourth dimension a hexagonal prisma with the hexagonal sides
$$(0,-1,-1,-1), (-1,0,-1,-1), (-1,1,0,-1), (0,1,1,-1), (1,0,1,-1), (1,-1,0,-1)$$
and
$$(0,-1,-1,1), (-1,0,-1,1), (-1,1,0,1), (0,1,1,1), (1,0,1,1), (1,-1,0,1)$$
Again, it is readily checked that those points all lie in a three-dimensional space. Also, it is just as easily checked that they indeed lie on the border of the tesseract.

Now all that remains is to cut through this with a plane. Let's take the plane that cuts off the corners at $(0,-1,-1,-1)$ and $(0,1,1,1)$ by cutting the adjacent sides of the respective hexagons in the middle. This condition fixes the  four points
$$(\frac{1}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},-1),
(-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1,-1),
(-\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{2},1),
(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1,1)$$
The other four points of the octagon are then found by intersecting the plane through those points with the four lines connecting related non-cut off corners of the two hexagons.

If I didn't miscalculate, they should be
$$(-1,0,-1,-\frac13), (-1,1,0,\frac13), (1,0,1,\frac13), (1,-1,0,-\frac13)$$

Comment: The intuitive idea is interesting. But as, in particular for a tesseract, the notions of inside and outside are no longer valid, I am looking forward to see the coordinates of the vertices of this octagon.

Comment: @JeanMarie: How do you get the idea that the concepts of "inside" and "outside" are not valid for a tesseract?

Comment: Great! A hexagonal prism works. Your 4D-vision is much better than mine! (I misguidedly, in now deleted comments under the OP, expressed a doubt whether this is possible at all.)

Comment: @celtschk Have you seen animations of the tesseract like this one : (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t-WyreE9ZkI)

Comment: @JeanMarie: Those are three-dimensional projections of the tesseract, moreover without hidden line/face removal. If you look at corresponding two-dimensional projections of the cube, you also don't recognize the inside and outside. For example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=syl5Yk25E-g (but be aware that your brain adds back the third dimension, so make sure you actively avoid that).

Comment: Splendid work on the coordiantes: I am completely convinced now. Besides, you are right: the notion of interior and exterior are modified by the fact that we see a projection into 3D.